# Serialization Exception : data contract is not expected

Tags: c#, serialization

I receive the following exception message while serializing an object to XML:

```
{"Type 'Alerter.EmailSender' with data contract name  'EmailSender:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Alerter' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."}
```

This is the class that i am trying to serialize an object of it to an XML File:

```
namespace Alerter
{
  [DataContract]
  public class EmailSender : IAction
  {
    private EmailSetting _emailSetting;
    private SmtpClient _smtpClient;
    [DataMember]
    public bool IncludeFullDetails
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string[] Receivers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public EmailSender()
    {
        _emailSetting = new EmailSetting();
        SetupClient();
    }

    private void SetupClient()
    {
        // Some Logic
    }


    public void Report(LogDictionary logDictionary)
    {
       // Some Logic
    }
   }
 }
```

That's the code i use for serialization:

```
 using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            DataContractSerializer ser =
                new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Rule>));
            ser.WriteObject(writer, list);
        }
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have specified this `EmailSender` class as a known type to your serializer using the [`proper constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259.aspx):

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(
    typeof(List<Rule>), 
    new[] { typeof(EmailSender) }
);
ser.WriteObject(writer, list);
```

The reason you need this is because probably in the object graph of the `Rule` class you only have used the `IAction` interface for all members and the serializer doesn't even know about the existence of the `EmailSender` implementation.

You should do the same for all other types which are not statically known in the `Rule` object graph.